# Programmatically move/animate a UITableView row from one position to another

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView and I want to programmatically move one row from position N1 to position N2 and I would like it to animate from the old location to the new. I've looked through the UITableView documentation and I'm only seeing inserts, reloads, and deletes. Do you know of a way I can do this programmatically?

A couple of notes:

- I know that I can animate the deletion from location N1 and animate the insertion to location N2 at the same time. That's my fallback, but I'd like the user to understand that it is truly moving from N1 to N2.
- I'm not talking about allowing the user to drag it from one place to another. I understand how to do that, I'm looking for a way to initiate and animate the move programmatically.

Comment: Delete/insert enclosed with beginUpdates/endUpdates doesn't help?

Comment: That still provides me with an effect where the row at location N1 slides out left (that's the animation style I'm using) and then the row slides back in at location N2. I'm looking for something that is visually akin to when the user drags it to a new location. For example, if it needs to move up 3 rows that the cell just slides up 3 rows and the other rows close in around the N1 space and open to up all the row to land in the N2 space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've dealt with something kind of like this in the past and the solution is not pretty but it does work.

Basically you have to do some math to calculate where on the screen the row is. Then adjust that based on the `y` property of the `contentOffset` of your `UITableView`.

You can do that like this:

```
[myView convertPoint:localPosition toView:nil];
```

Then you would construct a new `UIView` that's identical to your view. Set its frame to be directly on top of the `UITableViewCell` you're trying to move. Add it as a subview of your app's main `UIWindow`.

You'll want to set `userInteractionEnabled` or `scrollEnabled` to `NO` on your `UITableView` while all of this is going on so that the user can't muck with the position of things throughout the process (just remember to set it back to `YES` when everything is done animating).

Then animate it to the new position however makes the most sense.

I understand you may have to scroll the `UITableView` in the process of all of this, which complicates things considerably, but you *can* animate that scrolling as well.

You'll of course have to do similar operations on the row you're animating *to* if it is necessary in your app.

Like I said its not easy or pretty. But I *do* understand what you're trying to accomplish and I think the effect is super awesome when it's pulled off properly.

If anyone has a better idea of how to pull this off without going insane I'd love to know, but this type of implementation is the best I've been able to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm going to wait another day or two to see if I can get any others, but if not then I'll accept this answer. If this is the best I can do then I'm just going to stick with my fallback solution. 2 lines of code that gets me a near perfect solution is better than a very complex and potentially fragile solution. Thank you very much though for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Nice workaround. Is there an app that implements this? I'd like to see how good it looks before spending time implementing it.

Comment: I have a implementation at https://bitbucket.org/elmalabarista/dragdroptableviews. The animation is crap... that is where I get stuck

Answer (score 1):

```
[table beginUpdates];
[table moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:destIndexPath];
[table endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using iOS 5 or hight you could use the method:

```
- (void)moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
```

For example:

```
//move last cell one row up.
NSIndexPath *oldPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[items count] - 1 inSection:0];
NSIndexPath *newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[items count] - 2 inSection:0];
[[self tableView] moveRowAtIndexPath:oldPath toIndexPath:newPath];
```

Check out apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW55).

I guess your best fallback would indeed be the deletion and insertion method, something like:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:oldPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newNewPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
[tableView endUpdates];
```